# How to install app inventor onto Samsung intercept?

Tags: android

I am trying to install app inventor  on my Samsung intercept.  I have gone through the steps in the set up computer and phone.  When it was time to plug in the USB connection the two notifications did not display.  Please, if anyone knows of any additional steps I need to take I would appreciate some advise.

Comment: This should be posted on superuser.com

Comment: @Jamie Keeling Actually there is a new site http://android.stackexchange.com/ which is most appropriate for these kind of questions.

Comment: @Jamie Keeling and @Mayra, Google's App Inventor is a developer tool for Android. You telling Will to go post his question on the android user forum would be just like me telling someone else to post a question about adb or TraceView on the user forum. His question belongs here.

Comment: @Will, I didn't get this issue on my phones (but then again, I don't own an Intercept). Until someone points you in the right direction, I'd suggest you debug your app one snapshot at a time with the 'Package for Phone > Show Barcode' menu (located on the right upper side of your Designer window)

Comment: I've had no issues with mine once I performed a factory reset on the device (HTC Desire)

Comment: What type of computer (Windows? Mac? Linux?) - I also have an Intercept, and getting a USB connection is soooo flaky. I don't know if it's the cable or phone, but it seems like I just have to keep plugging and unplugging it until I randomly get a connection.

Answer (score 0):

Will is correct, i too have an intercept and it does not connect to app inventor. I believe it is something to do with the fact that there is no driver for windows 7 for the intercept. A driver separate from the mass storage drive driver.